# Spark job fails with org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I am running a spark job with following properties:

```html
 "spark.driver.disk": "10g",
  "spark.driver.maxResultSize": "40g",
  "spark.driver.memory": "50g",
  "spark.driver.memoryOverhead": "85g",
  "spark.executor.cores": "5",
  "spark.executor.disk": "60g",
  "spark.executor.instances": "400",
  "spark.executor.memory": "40g",
  "spark.executor.memoryOverhead": "37g",
  "spark.kubernetes.executor.limit.cores": "5",
  "spark.kubernetes.executor.request.cores": "5",
  "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions": "4000"
```

But somehow while writing the dataframe to parquet it is failing with following error:

```html
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: The relative remote executor(Id: 304), which maintains the block data to fetch is dead.
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:686)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.next(CompletionIterator.scala:29)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.nextCur(Iterator.scala:484)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:490)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:225)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec.$anonfun$doExecute$1(SortExec.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
```

I have tried persisting dataframe even did a count before writing but only write fails. Here output datasize is 500GB and I have defined repartition number as 1000 before writing. Any help is appreciated as I am stuck with this issue.

Comment: I have the same issue and can't seem to solve it. Sometimes it occurs for the same jobs and sometimes it's fine and has no issues. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I came across similar issues recently, and it was a bear to solve. The number one thing that helped was investigating the code and finding where we were using the most memory, and we found an inefficient pivot that was attempting to make a very wide DataFrame all in memory, and changing that helped bring the memory issue under control.

Aside from that, here's a few things you can try.

During debugging, we tested doing a repartition in the code right before writing out. This seems to have helped, since when we did the repartition amount >= the number of executors, we got 503 Slowdown from Amazon S3 for writing too fast, and that required further Spark tuning to solve, but at least it stopped showing the FetchFailedException.

```
df = df.repartition(cores*executors)
df.write.parquet(output_path)
```

Some more Spark tuning options that helped a bit with the memory issues:

```
”spark.driver.extraJavaOptions”: "-Xss1g"
“spark.executor.extraJavaOptions”: "-Xss1g"
“spark.memory.storageFraction”: “0.3”
```

Comment: at 3500 writes/second/shard, it is easy to overload s3 when writing a deep hive-partition-table style tree. The 503 responses from s3 should be handled in the s3 connector with backoff and retry. Which one were you using (emr, s3a?). if it is s3a, the stack trace would be interesting.

Comment: I was using EMR, and ended up resolving 503 by using AIMD retry strategy

Comment: interesting. i would expect EMR to handle it. there may be a tuning parameter as to how many retries before giving up.